Как получить доступ к объекту bot из импортируемого модуля
Просьба помочь в следующем вопросе.
После запуска телеграм-бота скрипт на Python начинает выполнять ряд операций. В какой-то момент скрипт должен отправить в чат телеграма короткое сообщение о текущем состоянии своей работы. Для отправки можно использовать метод bot.send_message(chat_id, text), но в данном случае объект bot создается внутри функции и никак не пойму как к нему получить доступ из другого импортируемого модуля.
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from config import TOKEN
from app.handlers import router
from app.database.models import async_main

async def main():
  await async_main()
  
  bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
  dp = Dispatcher()
  dp.include_router(router)
  
  await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  try:
    asyncio.run(main())
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Exit")
  except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", str(e))


Просто в аргументы функции добавь bot и наследуй его от Bot
@router.message()
async def foo(message: Message, bot: Bot):
    await bot.send_message(...)

